# Calculating averages in django models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web

I need to find out the average amount of quantity of a customers orders. How would I do this using django's models?

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    average_quantity_size = ?

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not be a model field. It should be a property.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=17)

    @property
    def average_quantity_size(self):
        qty = self.order_set.values_list('quantity', flat=True)
        if not qty:
            return 0
        return sum(qty)/len(qty)
```

The reverse lookups can be read here: [Lookups that span a relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`

Comment: Where are you doing the addition? Is definitely not this code..please look at the stacktrace closely

Comment: I'm not doing addition, this is the same code you posted `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\mysite\polls\models.py", line 11, in average_quantity_size
    return sum(qty)/len(qty)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) might be helpful.
It would still be a property, but may take this form:

```
@property
def average_quantity_size(self):
    result = self.orders.aggregate(Avg('quantity'))
    return result
```

But i highly recommend taking a look at the docs on aggregation linked above to get a clearer picture. good luck.